# How to stop timer when JFrame is disposed?

Tags: java

I got a timer that runs when `EasyGame` class is successfully running.

```
public class GameTimer extends Thread
{
    EasyGame game = null;
    
    public GameTimer(EasyGame popup)
    {
        game = popup;
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            sleep(60000);
            game.setVisible(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your score is: " + game.getScore());
            game.setVisible(false);
          
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong:" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I click close on the `EasyGame` class, it is disposed of but the timer still continues to run when I exited it. If I use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, it completely shuts down the entire application so I want to dispose of it instead. How do I get this timer to stop when the `EasyGame` class is disposed?

Comment: `if(game )` ... are you missing a `!= null` ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was typing that in an attempt to stop the timer. It shouldn't be there.

Comment: What does that mean "stop this timer' You sleep for 60 seconds do you want to "interrupt" that sleep?

Comment: Yes. The sleep goes on to continue even though I closed the JFrame.

Comment: What is the point of this? I would get annoyed if a popup is displayed every 60 seconds.

Comment: Its a timer for a game. When the 1 min is up, the pop up gets displayed to indicate that the game is over and shows how much the user scored.

Answer (score 2):

Your "timer" class is a bit pointless. Instead of sleeping try a swing [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html).

```
Timer timeout = new Timer( 60000, evt->{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your score is: " + game.getScore());
}
timeout.setRepeats( false );
timeout.start();
```

Then add a [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) to your frame. That way you can stop the timer.

```
frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent evt){
        timeout.stop();
    }
});
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
```

I'm assuming frame is a JFrame. DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE will cause your JFrame to close, but it won't exit the application unless it is the last window.

Comment: Thank you, I shall try this out.